# The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json;

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I have logout page in my web api controller. I am able to hit url and i am clearing cookies but response i am getting is The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json;
Below is my code.

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("~/api/auth/logout")]
        //Log out code
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {

            var currentCookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("session").FirstOrDefault();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            if (response!= null)
            {
                var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session", "")
                {
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    Domain = currentCookie.Domain,
                    Path = currentCookie.Path
                };
                response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
            }
            else
            {
            return response
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created filter as below.

```
public class Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            var response = actionExecutedContext.Response;
            var request = actionExecutedContext.Request;

            var currentCookie = request.Headers.GetCookies("session").FirstOrDefault();
            if (currentCookie != null)
            {
                var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session", "")
                {
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    Domain = currentCookie.Domain,
                    Path = currentCookie.Path
                };

                response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }
```

Decorated filter in action method as below.

```
[Route("~/api/auth/logout")]
[Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var message = string.Format("Logged Out");
    HttpError msg = new HttpError(message);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, msg);
}
```

It started working.